# Flutter Error : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: use clean project and also try to sync the Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by deleting the folder ".gradle" in "C:\Users<user>", user = your username, after you delete it, run your app and the BuildTools Sdk 29.0.2 will install automatically.
This is a common error for beginners to Flutter.